# Magento Layout updates for specific module

Tags: magento, layout

Lets suppose I want to add a `CSS` file on a particular Action, its easy with `<module_controler_action>` and if I use `<default>` it will apply to every page, but what if my module contains 100 actions (pages) and I want to add a `CSS` file only to specific module pages, how can I do that without applying to to every page of magento?

please help

Comment: just found the answer on this page http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/layout-update-for-all-actions-of-a-controller

Answer (score 0):

to add CSS only for particular module then add your CSS file in the following tag `<module_controller>`

Comment: No it doesn't work, I have tried it before and I have tried it again but I have to mention the Action too for it to work properly. The problem is that its not a single file I have to add 50 lines to every Action, and my Layout files has crossed 2000 lines, its hard to scroll up and down. i could include those 50 lines in `<default>` tag and it works but then it applies to all those pages where i don't want it to include.

Comment: just found the answer on this page
[link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/layout-update-for-all-actions-of-a-controller)